# Changing the pointer in Joomla to go to other than index.php

Tags: joomla

We have a Joomla installation sitting in the same exact root folder as the client's old system, which is html-based.  As it happens, the server will jump on "index.php" before it will look at "index.html" so it works out well as far as ease of deployment.  The problem is that we've had to take it down to make some tweaks, and the way I did that was to just rename the file `"_index.php"`.  That way, we can still look at it, by putting a "_" in front of the filename and going directly at it, but we have to do that every time we hit a menu item, which is annoying.

Is there a way to tell Joomla that the main filename is `"_index.php"` (or something else, for that matter) instead of "index.php"?  This way we can test all we want, without having to add the "_" by hand every time we render a page.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve while replacing my joomla site with wordpress.
I installed Wordpress to a subfolder , renamed the original index.php from joomla in the webroot and copied wordpress's index.php(you have to modify it accordingly) and .htacces to the root and added these rewrite rules to .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ younameit.php/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by editing the htaccess.txt to redirect to the renamed _index.php.  Sometimes it is renamed to .htaccess , it all depends on the web host configuration.

It sounds like you could benefit from a development version of your joomla site for testing so that you don't need to make these live tweaks to your publicly accessible site.  Have you considered putting the Joomla installation under source control?

Comment: I looked at that earlier; there seem to be a couple places in that file that reference the index.php file in a "renaming" node.  I will try tweaking it.

I'm sure it makes sense to do that.  This was our first run at a Joomla site and we did everything on the client's space at Yahoo.  I'm a Msft shop and I don't normally use MySql or php, so I really don't have any local resources devoted to it.  I enjoyed working with it, though, and will set it up better next time.

Comment: I reworked that htaccess.txt file, changing any references I found from "index.php" to "_index.php" and then I saved it back to the server. It had no effect. I re-copied it over as "htaccess.htaccess" and that didn't work either.  I tried ".htaccess" (i.e. no prefix) but the server would not permit that.  Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The file should be ".htaccess" and you need to save it to the root directory.  If you're having problems, then it might be a permission and/or ownership issue.  Correct that, if necessary.  You need to enable "Use Apache mod_rewrite" under "Global Configuration" in the back end.  Everything should work after that.